# powershell script unable to locate certain files when executed from a windows service

Tags: c#, powershell, service

I have a powershell script which spits out file information for a given file. The script is executed in a process from a windows service like so:

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo s = new ProcessStartInfo();
s.FileName = "powershell.exe";
s.Arguments = "./script.ps1";
s.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
s.RedirectStandardError = true;
s.UseShellExecute = false;
s.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo = s;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
/* ... defined output handlers ... */
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

The powershell script is as follows:

```
function ChangeDir($dir)
{
    try
    {
        echo ("Attempting to change directory: {0}" -f ($dir))
        Set-Location -Path $dir -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch
    {
        echo $error[0].Exception
    }
}

function OutputFileInfo($filePath)
{
    try
    {
        echo ("Attempting to read file: {0}" -f ($filePath))
        $file = @(Get-ChildItem $filePath -ErrorAction Stop)
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $file.Count; $i++)
        {
            echo ("{0},{1}" -f ($file[$i].Name, $file[$i].Length))
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        echo $error[0].Exception
    }
}

ChangeDir "/Windows/System32/drivers"
OutputFileInfo "tcpip.sys"
```

The output when running the powershell script from the command line is as I expect it to be:

```
Attempting to change directory: /Windows/System32/drivers 
Attempting to read file: tcpip.sys 
tcpip.sys,2773400
```

When the script executes via the windows service the output is this:

```
Attempting to change directory: /Windows/System32/drivers
Attempting to read file: tcpip.sys
Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\tcpip.sys' because it does not exist.
```

For other files it works perfectly fine from the command line and the service. Could it have something to do with the service running the powershell script as SYSTEM which somehow doesn't have access to that file? Although if that were the case I would expect a permissions error instead of a file not found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.... this was because system32/drivers is not accessible for 32bit applications that run on 64bit machines and I didn't realize I had my application set to the default in visual studio which I guess is 32bit. I changed it to 64bit and it works from the service now.